# Open-source Data Visualization dashboard

Tags: data-visualization, dashboard

We are looking for some open source technologies which can show a dashboard similar to the below picture. This has images for stores and data will be pulled against predefined points.

We evaluated Grafana - but struggling to get this. is there any other dashboard tools which can help with this.

[image: image of stores and data that will be pulled against predefined points]

Answer (score 2):

[HighCharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) it's an excellent chart library that can help you:

Check out [General drawing sample](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer)

[image]

or maybe [Network graph](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/network-graph)

[image]